# TLS handshake timeout while fetching oauth2 token

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, terraform

While trying to delete a google cloud instance I keep getting the follwowing error. Same error is seen while creating the VM. A few minutes ago while creating the instance my google chrome browser had hung for a long time many application were not working as expected. I had restart my system an after that I keep getting this error. How to get rid of this error?

```
* google_compute_instance.default: google_compute_instance.default: Error reading Instance kubewithssh: Get https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/crucial-bonsai-109417/zones/us-central1-a/instances/kubewithssh?alt=json: oauth2: can not fetch token: Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case root cause was insufficient resources. After increasing the limits for the deployment in Kubernetes manifest, issue was resolved.

However, Google has a recommended steps to investigate this issue. See most recent document [Troubleshooting | Connect documentation](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/multicluster-management/connect/troubleshooting#oauth_error)

### oauth2: cannot fetch token errors

**Symptom**

You might encounter an error like this one:

```
...  dialer: dial: connection to gkeconnect.googleapis.com:443 failed
after 388.080605ms: serve: egress call failed: rpc error: code =
Unauthenticated desc = transport: oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token: read tcp 192.168.1.40:5570->1.1.1.1:80
read: connection reset by peer
```

**Possible causes**

This can mean that the upstream HTTP proxy reset the connection, most likely because this particular URL is not allowed by your HTTP proxy. In the example above, the 1.1.1.1:80 is the HTTP proxy address.

**Resolution**

Check that your HTTP proxy whitelist includes the following URLs/domains:

```
gkeconnect.googleapis.com
oauth2.googleapis.com/token
www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs
```